# Generating client code with wsdl2js?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, wsdl2java

I am trying to use wsdl2js to generate the client-side handler of a SOAP request for a WSDL file but running into a few problems. If I use:

```
>wsdl2js -p [projectName] [wsdlFile]
```

it only generates a javascript file, which isn't what I need.

If I use

> wsdl2js -client [wsdlFile]

like they demonstrate, I get an "Unexpected option: -client"

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no -client option in wsdl2js. That's why you're getting the last-mentioned error.

The javascript file that is generated from a call like

```
>wsdl2js -p soap http://link.to/webservice?wsdlfile
```

will generate the stubs you need in order to communicate with the referenced webservice